optimize this python code that involves matrix inversion
So I have this line of code that involves a matrix inversion
X = A @ B @ np.linalg.pinv(S)

$A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix, $B$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix and $S$ is an $m$ by $m$ matrix. $m$ is smaller than $n$ but usually not orders of magnitude smaller. Usually $m \sim \frac{1}{2} n$. $S$ is a symmetrical positive definite matrix. How do I make this line of code run faster in python?
I realize I can do
X = np.linalg.solve(S.T, (A@B).T).T
but is there more I can do given $S$ is a symmetrical positive definite matrix?

Does $S$ change between executions of this line of code, or is it a fixed matrix?  If $S$ is symmetric and positive definite, then pinv(S) is simply $S^{-1}$.

If the same matrix $S$ is going to be used repeatedly,  then you can significantly speed up the solution process.

What implementation of BLAS/LAPACK are you using with Python?  np.show_config() can be helpful in figuring this out.    A high performance BLAS/LAPACK (such as Intel's MKL) can be much faster than the default libraries.

@BrianBorchers no S does change so i can't just save a copy of $S^{-1}$  I use openblas according to np.show_config(). is that ok?

@BrianBorchers How do I tell numpy to use MKL?

Are you matrices dense or sparse?

OpenBLAS is the fastest of the open source BLAS libraries.  MKL is somewhat faster but only runs on Intel (not AMD) processors.  You could install MKL (licenses are free but it is not open source) and configure numpy to use it.

Since S is SPD, you can (and should) use np.linalg.cholesky to get a cholesky factorization which will be ~2x faster than the LU factorization that np.linalg.solve uses.

Good answer. Also, one can get the benefits of cholesky without the manual work by using the wrapper scipy.linalg.solve with assume_a='pos' (note that this is scipy and not numpy).
